# Tap interface using netplan?

Tags: linux-networking, ubuntu-18.04

How does one set up tun and tap interfaces on systems that use netplan?

Normally you'd use pre-up in /etc/network/interfaces to call ip tuntap for creating the interface, but I haven't found anything in the netplan docs to do this.

Comment: I don't think I'd get too attached to netplan. From what I've seen, it's yet another of Canonical's crappy solutions to non-problems, and it's likely to go the way of the dodo (except they actually shipped it in an LTS Ubuntu, so some people are going to be stuck with it for years).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when upgrading to 18.04 broke my tap based OpenVPN server. It is quite annoying when a headless server just stops working because Ubuntu dropped support for defining bridges in /etc/network/interfaces. There are a few examples already but pretty much you need to create a .yaml file in /etc/netplan that looks something like one of the configs below. Note that you will need the `bridge-utils` package installed.

Replace `eth0` with the name of your ethernet device. You can find this using `ifconfig -a`.

Additionally you can set the MAC address of the bridge using the `macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` option where `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` is replaced with the address you want to use.

## /etc/netplan/00-bridge.yaml

### For DHCP:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eth0]
      dhcp4: true 
      dhcp6: no
```

### For a static IP:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eth0]
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.0.0.5/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      dhcp6: no
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do a tap interface from netplan yaml file, I think you will have to read in deep the reference manual from web page. It is possible the tunnel interface with gretap mode should be a solution. Anyway my advice is use the ip command in a boot script in systemd for example, if you wanna to configure it fast.

/usr/bin/tap.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

ip link add name br0 type bridge;
for i in `seq 0 5`; do
    ip tuntap add name tap$i mode tap;
    ip link set up dev tap$i;
    ip link set tap$i master br0;
done;
```

/lib/systemd/system/tap.service

```
[Unit]
Description=TAP Interfaces
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tap.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
$ sudo systemctl enable tap.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tap.service → /lib/systemd/system/tap.service.
```

Netplan docs: https://netplan.io/reference/#properties-for-device-type-tunnels%3A

Comment: Shouldn't this go into `/etc/systemd` rather than `/lib/systemd`? The latter may be overwritten.

Comment: Hi! No. Use /lib/systemd/system with filename and extension .service the standard way to work with unit files in systemd.

Comment: That's not correct, actually, see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd — `/lib` is reserved for system-installed packages. You should use `/etc` and override if necessary.

Comment: link is rotten. actual link to netplan docs: https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-yaml/